# Program works differently if I remove println! statement

Tags: rust

My attempt to make a simple guess the number game does not work if `println!("In the loop");` is commented out.

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..101);
    loop{
        // println!("In the loop");
        let mut guess = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        let mut guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };
        if secret_number == guess {
            println!("Correct");
            break;
        }else if secret_number > guess {
            print!("{} is smaller",guess);
        }else if secret_number < guess {
            print!("{} is bigger",guess);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit you question regarding what do you mean of 'not working'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `print!`s at the end don't print a newline, so the output isn't flushed before the next `stdin().read_line()`. Make them `println!`s.